# Why do I need fallback function here?

Tags: fallback-function

I have a `payable` function that transfers ether to contract.

```
function test(...) public payable returns (bool) {  
    ...                                                                                               
    address(this).transfer(msg.value); 

    return true;
}
```

I found that above method fails without having a fallback function in the contract.

```
function () payable public {}
```

Can anyone explain this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the line `address(this).transfer(msg.value);` is transferring `msg.value` worth of Ether from the contract to itself.

And if you send Ether to a contract without a payable fallback function it will fail.

Comment: so whenever I want to send ether to a contract I must have a fallback function?

Comment: Im not sure what version of solidity it started in, but by default if you dont have a payable fallback function you can't just send ETH to that contract. (This doesn't include other payable functions). But the line `address(this).transfer(msg.value);` is redundant anyway, the entire msg.value automatically goes to the contract, you don't have to manually set it.